# PDF annotator iPhone

Tags: iphone, drawing

I am trying to write an app that shows a PDF and allows a user to scribble all over it with their finger and then save the "annotated" pdf on close, seeing their changes again when they reopen the app.

Currently, I have thrown a UIWebview Up and tried to put a UIView over the top of it as a drawing layer.

Is this the best approach? is there an answer already out there? Any examples?

Thanks.

Comment: This question seems to be substantially the same as your previous (unanswered) question on this topic. It would be better to edit that one than to post a new, only slightly different question.

Comment: *sigh* losing my faith in this forum lol... One is asking for help with one particular approach to the problem, the other is asking for a holistic approach/guidance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, putting a transparent UIView on top and painting the users touches in this one is what I would do too.

Maybe [this project](https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View) can help you.

Comment: Hey Dude, Not quite - I have no issues drawing, its just doing so ontop of a PDF

Comment: Well I did some custom drawing too and it turns out there are a lot of optimisations you can use to make it fast&responsive. Using a well-proven framework for this is always a good idea :)
Also make sure to not fill your CGContext with a white background colour, that was a mistake I did once.